# Dotnet-Isolated Azure Functions - how to access Certificates from request

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, middleware

I am currently developing middleware for a an isolated-process .NET 7 function app (coded in C#). It appears that the new architecture uses a new class called "HttpRequestData" to represent the call. Body, Headers, and other information is stored here but there exists no Request.GetClientCertificate() like one can use for MVC projects. This appears to be due to the lack of access to the HttpContext. Therefore, I would think that FunctionContext class would include this but I don't see any methods that refer to this.

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: for access Certificates from request hope [this](https://github.com/umamimolecule/azure-functions-http-middleware) [helps](https://damienbod.com/2020/09/04/securing-azure-functions-using-certificate-authentication/)

Comment: Thank you Sampath, I was able to solve this without needing to upgrade to an app service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the answer myself.

Function Apps, like App Services need to explicitly be set to allow certificates.

This is done for app services through powershell like this
az webapp update --set clientCertEnabled=true --name  --resource-group

I was able to use this command
az functionapp update --set clientCertEnabled=true --name  --resource-group

Which made the certificate available in a header called x-arr-clientcert